# WordPress WP_User_Query using taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I recently added taxonomies to my user settings page using [this](https://www.nopio.com/blog/add-user-taxonomy-wordpress/) tutorial and the ACF taxonomy field, although I didn't see anyway to query on taxonomy based on [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user_query/) documentation I figured I would just try it using these arguments:

```
$args = [
  'role' => 'gebruiker',
  'number' => $limit,
  'offset' => $offset,
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'category_level',
      'terms' => 36,
      'field' => 'term_id',            
    )
  )
]
```

But it doesn't work and just returns every user that matches the other arguments, so I was wondering if it is at all possible to query based on taxonomy and if so, how do I do this? :)

Comment: Why are you using the ACF taxonomy field if you've gone and built the taxonomies yourself?  I don't use ACF with any frequency whatsoever but it's possible that it's not actually saving the data as taxonomies.

Comment: ACF saves the data as meta data. You'd have to post more information about what you're trying to do and usage. But you might want to look at this: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to-get-values-from-a-user/

Comment: I have not implemented taxonomies for users before, ever, but, following the nopio tutorial, it only says you can use the WP_User_Query class like so instead of yours:

$args = [
  'role' => 'gebruiker',
  'number' => $limit,
  'offset' => $offset,
  'meta_key'    => USER_CATEGORY_META_KEY,
  'meta_value'  => 36,
  'meta_compare'    => 'LIKE'
 ];
It has no example to query by 'tax_query' or 'taxonomy', do you have a 'meta_key' to query by?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Altough I never did figure out the issue, I did find a solution that works for me ;)

```
$args = [
  'key' => 'specialty',
  'value' => '47',
  'compare' => '='
]

WP_User_Query($args);
```

Returns only 2 users, which is what I expected since only 2 users have the `specialty` taxonomy set to a term with the ID 47! But as soon as I wrapped this query in a `meta_query` tag (see below) so I could add more parameters such as the users `role`. It would return every user matching the `role` query.

```
$args = [
  'meta_query' => [
    'key' => 'specialty',
    'value' => '47',
    'compare' => '='
  ]
]

WP_User_Query($args);
```

So, what I ended up doing was writing a custom MySQL query to fetch the ids of the users which had to custom taxonomy set, afterwards I could use the normal `WP_Query` with the `role` parameter and I just added the `include` parameter with the previously found IDs